# Scrape all hostnames with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I noticed that some of the websites I am trying to scrape redirect me to a different hostname: https://www.citibank.com.au/ redirects for example to https://www1.citibank.com.au/. While Scrapy does scrape regular subdomains ([www.subdomain.example.com](http://www.subdomain.example.com)), it skips www2.example.com.

This is the apparently how Scrapy is supposed to work: https://doc.ebichu.cc/scrapy/ that:

> OffsiteMiddleware
> classscrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware Filters out
> Requests for URLs outside the domains covered by the spider.
>
> This middleware filters out every request whose host names aren’t in
> the spider’s allowed_domains attribute. All subdomains of any domain
> in the list are also allowed. E.g. the rule [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) will also
> allow bob.www.example.org **but not www2.example.com** nor example.com.

My question is: how would I make sure that all subdomains that have a different hostname (e.g. www2.example.com) are scraped?

The solution I could think of is to populate the allowed domains list with all variations of an url (e.g. [www.example.com,www1.example.com,www2.example.com,etc.]). Is this the way to go, or is there any option I have overlooked in the Scrapy documentation that could fix this in a nicer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way the `allowed_domains` is supposed to work in scrapy. It's meant to filter any requests that go offsite from the domains you allowed.

If you want your scrapy to reach several offsite domains, **you don't need to use** the `allowed_domains` attribute, just remove it from your spider (or leave it empty) and requests will get through.

In the specific case you mentioned, if they are all part of the same domain and you are having problem with mirrors (`"www1..." "www2..."`) use just the actual domain.

```
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
```